# Password validation

Tags: php

I developed code in PHP but it's not working. Sometimes the code works but most of the time not. The problem is in showing whether the password is valid or not.sorry friends i forgot to changed that but my problem with it only show invalid even i entered valid user name and password..plz help me

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("billmailid", $con);
        if (!$con)
            {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
$username=$_POST['usernameid'];
$password=$_POST['passwordid'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");


$check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username = '$username' && password= '$password'") ;

$check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

if($check2==1)
  {
   echo "valid";
  }
else
  {
  echo "invalid";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please write your question in body not in title. And what exactly doesn't work? But reading your code i can say that using OR operator (||) is really not what you want - use AND operator instead. [Read about logical operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html).

Comment: Watch out for sql injection! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: XKCD - sql injection comment isn't the same without this comics :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off all it would be great if you rephrase the question title and body, add examples, errors and in general - make it readable.

Second in SQL `||` is `OR` and `&&` is `AND`. You should probably start from there.

Third - you should really read about SQL Injection. And I don't mean the XKCD comics.
In the [following link](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/11/05/preventing-sql-injection-attack/) you can find few examples and guidelines about how the make clear and safe query for both your database and your users

Forth - You better not use user empty root password and defiantly not use the "root" as the website user.

Writing save code is sometimes pain, but the sooner you start the more natural it comes. furthermore "making" application secure is much harder than building it safe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AND not || in your mysql query would be a good start.  More importantly, you have a gaping security hole. Escape the input

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Otherwise, it's not a bad start, keep trying, you're not a million miles away.

Answer (score 0):

Other that being vulnerable to sql injection there are a few things.

You have an unnecessary mysql query, `$result` is a mysql query but doesn't get used.

Your query for check uses `||`which is `OR` it should be `&&` or `AND` this means the login only has to match one of the two values to bring back a result. This causes several problems.

A request only needs to match one of the two values, so any valid username or password even if they don't pair up result in row being returned.
or
If two logins have the same password you would get 2 rows back which would mean that the `if($check==1)` statement would fail.